# Getting list of string array into separate string arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, tokenize

This is my code.

```
SENTENCE = "He sad might have lung cancer. It’s just a rumor."
sent=(sent_tokenize(SENTENCE))
```

The output is

```
['He sad might have lung cancer.', 'It’s just a rumor.']
```

I want to get this array as

```
['He sad might have lung cancer.']
['It’s just a rumor.']
```

Is their any way of doing this and if so how?

Comment: Um, is there a reason you want each string to be in a list? Doesn't seem to make much sense.. unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `[[x] for x in ['He sad might have lung cancer.', 'It’s just a rumor.']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to split according to a sentence, you can simply do this:

```
sentence_list = SENTENCE.split('.')
for sentence in sentence_list:
    single_sentence = [sentence + '.']
```

If you actually want all lists containing a single sentence in the same data structure, you'd have to use a list of lists or a dictionary:

```
my_sentences = []

sentence_list = SENTENCE.split('.')
for sentence in sentence_list:
    my_sentences.append([sentence + '.'])
```

To shorten this out using a list comprehension:

```
my_sentences = [[sentence + '.'] for sentence in SENTENCE.split('.')]
```

with the only culprit being that the SENTENCE splitting part will happen more often so it'll be slower working with a massive amount of sentences.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `re.split()` function:

```
import re 

s = "He sad might have lung cancer. It’s just a rumor."
parts = [l if l[-1] == '.' else l + '.' for l in re.split(r'\.\s?(?!$)', s)]
print(parts)
```

The output:

```
['He sad might have lung cancer.', 'It’s just a rumor.']
```

---

`r'\.\s?(?!$)'` pattern, defines separator as `.` except that which is at the end of the text `(?!$)`

`l if l[-1] == '.' else l + '.'` - *recovering* `.` at the end of each line(as the dilimiter was not captured while splitting)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even this answer is not what I expected, this also a new thing that I learnt from your answer.